# How to create a wildcard redirect with sinatra

Tags: heroku, sinatra

I recently had problems upgrading to the new cedar stack on Heroku. So I worked around it by dumping my old website into a static public folder powered by the sinatra code below.

However, links to the old urls don't load the static pages because they are failing to append .html to the end of the urls.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

set :public, Proc.new { File.join(root, "public") }

before do
  response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'public, max-age=100' # 5 mins
end

get '/' do
  File.read('public/index.html')
end
```

How can I append .html to the end of all urls? would it be something like this:

```
get '/*' do
  redirect ('/*' + '.html')
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either get the path matched via the `params[:splat]` or from the helper `request.path_info`, I tend to use the second:

```
get '/*' do
  path = params[:splat].first # you've only got one match
  path = "/#{path}.html" unless path.end_with? ".html" # notice the slash here!
  # or
  path = request.path_info
  path = "#{path}.html" unless path.end_with? ".html" # this has the slash already
  # then
  redirect path
end
```

Comment: Great! Works a treat! Many Thanks.